# Return json object when notification is clicked

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I'm building an android app which supports push notifications using phonegap/cordova and this [plugin](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova). The plugin has an onMessage() method which is triggered whenever a push notification is received, this method returns a json object to my javascript plugin. However I want this method to return the json only when the notification on status bar is clicked.

This is my onMessage() method:

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String message = "", title = "", type = "";
    int msgctn = 0, schoolid = 0, studentid = 0, contentid = 0;

    // Extract the payload from the message
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
      try
      {
          message = extras.getString("message");
          title = extras.getString("title");
          type = extras.getString("type");
          msgctn = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("msgctn"));
          schoolid = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("schoolid"));
          studentid = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("studentid"));
          contentid = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("contentid"));

        JSONObject json;
        json = new JSONObject().put("event", "message");

        json.put("message", message);
        json.put("type", type);
        json.put("contentid", contentid);
        json.put("schoolid", schoolid);
        json.put("studentid", studentid);

        GCMPlugin.sendJavascript( json );
        // Send the MESSAGE to the Javascript application
      }
      catch( JSONException e)
      {
        Log.e(ME + ":onMessage", "JSON exception");
      }

      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, App4.class);
      notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

      NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
          .setContentText(message)
          .setContentTitle(title)
          .setSmallIcon(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? R.drawable.icon : android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
          .setAutoCancel(true)
          .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
          .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
          //.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
          .setLights(-16711681, 2000, 1000)
          .setNumber(msgctn)
          .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifsound));

      Notification notification = builder.build();
      NotificationManager notificationManager = getNotificationManager(context);
      notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

    }
```

I had to create a notification object in order to show it on status bar. When the notification is clicked it calls intent App4, this shows the index.html of my app, but I want to execute some javascript function or return some json object to my app using the payload. Maybe I can call other function to do this, not an intent but I'm new on android world and don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is put the JSON data as extras in the notificationIntent Intent that you are creating. You can do this by calling the [putExtras()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.content.Intent%29) method of your notificationIntent, or do it manually. Whichever way you do it you need to get the data you want into the notificationIntent as extras.

Then when your App4 activity starts you will need catch the Intent in either [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) or [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) and check to see if the Intent or Bundle has the extras that you want. If it does then you create the JSON object and pass it to your javascript application just like you did in the onMessage() method you pasted.

You will also have to remove the code that sends the JSON object to your javascript application in the onMessage() method.

I hope that helps, it should work but I'm away from my computer and can't actually test the code.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved! Are you working with same plugin? Now I call sendJavascript from onNewIntent() method but calling  gwebView.sendJavascript( _d ) throws me a Null pointer exception. gwebView is set on execute method not in sendJavascript method, I think that's my problem but don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I'm not using the same plugin I just know a bit about GCM (we wrote a commercial Web service for it) and related issues. You might have to use something later in the lifecycle like onResume() because perhaps in onNewIntent() the widgets have not been created yet?